Error when building React Native: Could not find com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.19
When update gradle from 6.9 -> 7,2 and react-native from ^0.61.3 -> ^0.71.19.
I'm building react-native app using CI/CD to get apk. It show this error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-image-filter-kit:compileDebugRenderscript'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-image-filter-kit:debugCompileClasspath'.

Could not find com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.19.
Searched in the following locations:
- file:.../repository/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.71.19/react-native-0.71.19.pom
- file:/builds/clientprojects/assembler_projects/prd/project_name/src/node_modules/react-native/android/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.71.19/react-native-0.71.19.pom
- file:/builds/clientprojects/assembler_projects/prd/project_name/src/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.71.19/react-native-0.71.19.pom
- https://maven.google.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.71.19/react-native-0.71.19.pom
- https://www.jitpack.io/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.71.19/react-native-0.71.19.pom
- https://mvnrepository.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.71.19/react-native-0.71.19.pom
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.71.19/react-native-0.71.19.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.71.19/react-native-0.71.19.pom
- https://jitpack.io/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.71.19/react-native-0.71.19.pom
Required by:
project :react-native-image-filter-kit



I tried many solutions in the internet but still got this failed with the :react-native-image-filter-kit: package.
Checked with the issues list in the github but not found anything.
Please save my days. Thank you very much.

You are upgrading RN from 0.61 to 0.71 which is quite a big leap. Have you thought about upgrading to a version in between? Maybe that will resolve some of the issues you are having.
